# Youtube and Vimeo video return me NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: html, youtube, vimeo

I've added some video on a Shopify page, but I can see only grey box.
Looking at lan traffic I can see that the Youtube and Vimeo resource are blocked with NS_BINDING_ABORTED
[image]
Does anyone know why and how to fix the error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HTTP monitoring tools like Fiddler or HTTP Fox then check this link :
https://kb.webtrends.com/articles/Information/NS-BINDING-ABORTED-status-message-in-http-debugger/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle

otherwise please elaborate the question with your deployment environment, especially from a technical view of how you implemented this and getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You! I've used a standard video Shopify module, to give more detailed information I can indicate the url where the problem is visible: https://u-boatwatch.myshopify.com/pages/video

Comment: But I have to correct myself, the problem seems to afflict only the autoplay movies

Answer (score -1):

It could have been very much better if you would have elaborated your question.
I can give you an insight of what basically: NS_BINDING_ABORTED is.
NS_BINDING_ABORTED error happens because the browser is navigated away from the page before it receives a response from server(In your case: Shopify).
Hence, in short... There is no problem with your video, you shall refresh the page and attempt to see it again.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but before post my question I've tried several times to refresh my page, I've also tried with three different browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) and different PC but I'm never able to seen the video. Only sometimes I was able to ear the audio but never the video!